# How to implement a Multivariate multi-site application in LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, rnn

I am trying to make a multivariate multi-site classification LSTM model using Keras. I have followed this tutorial from Jason Brownlee: https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/.

This method removes the first few observations to create lags, which is not desired in my case.
I would like to change it to a one to one sequence model where it uses all previous observations to predict the classes instead of a fixed time frame. This is shown in Jason Brownlee's book
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU6Kd.png).

I have multiple ID's that each have their own sequence, with variable timesteps for each ID. I would like to predict the class of the next observation using all previous observations, and then do this for the whole sequence for each ID. I have made an example of the data in the table below. I would like to predict Class of row 2 using row 1. Then predict class of row 3 using row 1+2. Then predict class of row 4 using row 1+2+3. Then there is ID 2, so a new sequence, where I would like to do the same thing.

I couldn't find any examples on the topic. Does someone have example code how to:

1. Structure the data in a 3 dimensional way to use it for multivariate multi-class multi-site LSTM.
2. How to deal with uneven sequences (Probably padding)
3. How to implement this in the LSTM network

| ID | Date | feature1 | feature2 | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.2 | 0.7 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.4 | 0.1 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 0.2 | 0.9 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.3 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.2 | 0.1 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.3 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 0.3 | 0.1 | 1 |